# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encoding' when installing package with pip package

Tags: python, pip, bcrypt

I have a program that uses bcrypt and I would like to install the package if the user doesn't have bcrypt. It works on my PC at home running Python 3.7 and the latest version of pip but at school, it gives the error in the title. Here is the relevant code:

```
try:
import bcrypt
except ImportError:
    from pip._internal import main as pip  # if bcrypt cannot be installed, attempt installation
    print("Attempting to install bcrypt...")
    pip(["install","bcrypt"])
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\ths-fs-002\Student Work\2016\16HarveyJ\NEA-1\src\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main as pip  # if bcrypt cannot be installed, attempt installation
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.log import logger
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\log.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip import backwardcompat
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\backwardcompat\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    console_encoding = sys.__stdout__.encoding
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encoding'
```

Comment: I'd strongly advise to not install packages for the user inside an executable / script: it may cause various other kind of issues. Instead, issue a clear warning message, possibly telling the user how to install the package (e.g., with pip and the `--user`) option, then exit your program. For example, if the user gets the warning message, they may hesitate to install it, instead ask their system administrator, who can install the package system wide. Or a variety of other scenarios.

Comment: It may also be a matter of upgrading pip. Or downgrading, in case 3.4 isn't supported anymore.Try out pip on the command line first, to see if it works.

Comment: My school doesn't allow CMD access but I may try to use the subprocess library to install pip/bcrypt.

Comment: @9769953 My school has pip v1 so that's why it didn't work :p

Comment: Oh dear: seems your school requires a lot of a backward compability. Really unfortunate they don't update it.

Comment: NB: depending on the task at hand, you may be (a lot) better off using a live Jupyter notebook, for which you can construct the environment (packages etc) yourself, if you use a "binder". See for example https://mybinder.org/ (note: universities and schools start using these binders quite a bit for teaching. Perhaps they'll take the hint ;-).

Comment: My school blocks storing .exe files and running them of memory sticks, I'm better off trying my luck with a live Linux USB at this point :(

Comment: Binders run on the internet: remote server, accessed through a webpage. So if you don't need anything locally from your school's computers, that works very nicely. You can put your own code in a git repository, and automatically create a binder from it, being able to run your code anywhere without installing anything. Just as a note.

Comment: Sounds great, I may try that. Thanks!

Comment: @9769953 Is it possible to use a private Gitlab repository for Binder?

Comment: No: the code will  be public. (The alternative is setting up your own system, but that defeats the purpose here.) See [the FAQ in the mybinder documentation](https://mybinder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-secure-is-mybinder-org)